# is there a way to remove white outline when placing image on tk window?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

When I try to add an image from another directory to the tk window.
[This is the png file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Hyy.png).[This is what appears in the tk window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tkTj.png) The image has a white outline around it. The png file has no white outline so there must problem when its being added to the tk window. Here is the code so far below :

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
 
window = Tk()
window.configure(bg = '#73767A')

im = Image.open("static/logo.png")
im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.resize((400,225), Image.ANTIALIAS))
Label(image = im).place(x = 200, y = 0)
```

Comment: White letters on yellow background are hard to read.

Comment: @ack.... oh ok.

Comment: I have changed the yellow to a dark variation of yellow so that its easier to read with white text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can set the `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` attributes to zero.